# RpcIpcMessagePortClosedError: Cannot send the message

Tags: node.js, npm, apache-superset, npm-build

Doing the `npm run build` I'm getting the following error

```
RpcIpcMessagePortClosedError: Cannot send the message - the message port has been closed for the process 146400.
    at /home/superset/superset/superset-frontend/node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/lib/rpc/rpc-ipc/RpcIpcMessagePort.js:47:47
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: undefined,
  signal: undefined
}
```

I've seen solutions on how to do it through visual studio code but I'm running this code through command line in a remote server

I expect to finish the `npm run build`

Answer (score 0):

I think there's multiple Node processes running, My fix when i encounter this issue is just run it should be fix by killing all the node process if you are using Linux machine:`killall node`, and re run the command `npm run build`